# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException al recorrer for de manera invertida

Tags: java

Tengo problemas a la hora de recorrer el for de manera invertida, por ende, no entiendo cómo puedo hacer para desencriptar, ya que el código de encriptado sí que funciona. Es la letra "a" la que rompe el código.

Al llegar a la letra "a", da arroja este error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2
        at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:711)
        at ejercicioSiete.ejercicio7.main(ejercicio7.java:45)
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String frase1 = "vienen los romanos";
    String frase2 = "";

    int clave = 2;
    String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String ABC = abc.toUpperCase();

    for (int i = 0; i < frase1.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < abc.length(); j++) {
            if (frase1.charAt(i) == abc.charAt(j)) {
                if (j + clave >= abc.length()) {
                    frase2 += abc.charAt((j + clave % abc.length()) - (clave * 2));
                }
                else {
                    frase2 += abc.charAt((j + clave - (clave * 2)));
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(frase1);
        System.out.println(frase2);
        System.out.println(clave);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y coloca el error que te manda

Comment: Ya la actualicé, por si puedas echarle una ojeada.

Comment: En el código llegas a un punto donde en el else `j=0`  `clave=2` y en la formula `(j + clave - (clave * 2)) = -2` entonces abc.charAt(-2) es StringIndexOutOfBoundsException porque -2 no es un valor dentro del índice.

Comment: Claro, lo que necesito es que empiece a contarse desde atrás cuando aparece una a, pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: Considera cuando es negativo y súmale la longitud de tu alfabeto. Recuerda también aplicarle el módulo

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es considerar el caso cuando `j + clave` sea menor a `clave * 2`. En este caso como `clave` es igual a dos, el caso a considerar es que cuando tengas valores menores a 4.
Una solución es sumar el largo de `abc` con el resultado de `j + clave - (clave * 2)` y agregar una condición que te verifique que `j + clave` sea cuatro o mayor.

```
String frase1 = "vienen los romcnos";
String frase2 = "";
int clave = 2;
String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String ABC = abc.toUpperCase();

for (int i = 0; i < frase1.length(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < abc.length(); j++) {
        if (frase1.charAt(i) == abc.charAt(j)) {
            if (j + clave >= abc.length()) {
                frase2 += abc.charAt((j + clave % abc.length()) - (clave * 2));
            }
            else if(j + clave > 3) {
                frase2 += abc.charAt((j + clave - (clave * 2)));
            }
            else {
                frase2 += abc.charAt((abc.length()) + (j + clave - (clave * 2)));
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(frase2);
    System.out.println(frase1);
}
```